# Script to open a PDF with an in-document link in new tab in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, script, adobe-acrobat

I need to open PDFs from another pdf document in new tab. I found [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1034535) and it's working like charm:

a) in the Document-level script:

```
var myOpenInPlaceSetting = app.openInPlace ;
app.openInPlace = false ;
```

b) in the willClose Document Action:

```
app.openInPlace = myOpenInPlaceSetting ;
```

But I have to add this script manually several times in a day. Is there a way to simplify the process? Maybe some folder-level script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick is to create a blank one-page document, and add the code to it.

Then you add that page to your main document, and immediately delete it again.

The scripts are now migrated to the main document.

Comment: Thank you, it works! To automate further I created an action that adds and deletes my page.